# SimpleXMLElement: get the exact positions of different tags into the same parent

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <section>
        <p>Example text</p>
        <p>Another text</p>
        <img l:href="imagehref">
        <p>Some other text</p>
    </section>
</book>
```

I would like to make a readable text from this, so I'm parsing it with SimpleXMLElement and get this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement) {
  ["p"]=>
  array(3) {
    ...
  }
  ["image"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement) {
    }
  }
}
```

All tags are grouped by name, so i cannot determine where the picture is located into the text – just that it exists.

The question: is there any way to get the exact sequence of tags in `<section>`? Like this:

```
[0] => 'p',
[1] => 'p',
[2] => 'img',
[3] => 'p'
```

so that i could transform them into HTML in correct order?

Comment: what code do you use to create the XML? `simplexml_load_string`? Please post the code you use to create the SimpleXMLElement

Comment: @clayton it's `simplexml_load_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate over the child nodes of every `<section>` tag.

```
// Assumes your string is loaded, e.g.
// $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($xml->xpath('//section') as $section) {
    foreach($section->children() as $node) {
        echo $node->getName(), "\n";
    }
}
```

You can see that [this outputs](https://3v4l.org/k3t4N):

```
p
p
img
p
```